# Why opposite operation <> doesn't work on trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger which is `AFTER UPDATE`. I have a condition in that which doesn't work, How can I fix it?

```
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.colname <> OLD.colname THEN
        DELETE FROM tableX WHERE id = OLD.id;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

It should be noted if I write this `IF 1 THEN` then that `DELETE` query works. So the problem is that condition. What's wrong with it?

---

As *@Darwin von Corax* said in the comments, when one of these `NEW.colname`, `OLD.colname` is `null`, then all of that condition returns `false`. So I want to know how can I create a condition which acts like this ?

```
Null <> 10        -- true
Null <> Null      -- false
10 <> 12          -- true
32 <> Null        -- true
3 <> 3            -- false
```

Comment: Is it possible that either `NEW.colname` or `OLD.colname` is **`null`**? If so, then `<>` will return **`null`** which `if` would treat the same as **`false`**.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Oh yes, you are right .. I tested it and when one of those values is `null` then that condition doesn't work. So is there any solution?

Comment: Yes. Just give me a minute.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Ok, waiting for you. Just before writing an answer please take a look at my update. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either `NEW.colname` or `OLD.colname` is **`null`**, then `<>` will return **`null`** which `if` would treat the same as **`false`**.

Fortunately, there is a solution: the `<=>` (NULL-safe equality) operator, which returns `1` if both operands are **`null`** and `0` if only one is. The expression

```
IF NOT (NEW.colname <=> OLD.colname) THEN
```

should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just add logic for checking null conditions. It is not triggered when both columns are null which means that no changes happen.

```
$$
BEGIN
    IF 
        -- when exactly one of the column is null
        NEW.colname is not null and OLD.colname is null or 
        NEW.colname is null and OLD.colname is not null or 
        -- when both are not null compare their values
        NEW.colname is not null and OLD.colname is not null and NEW.colname <> OLD.colname THEN
        DELETE FROM tableX WHERE id = OLD.id;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Comment: Oh that's a long condition and I hardly think it work as well, because you have used `or`, so if just this part `NEW.colname is not null and OLD.colname is null` be `true` then the result of that `IF` is also `true`... which isn't what I need.

Comment: @stack, well it will trigger when one of the columns is null, isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: No no ... I want to execute that `DELETE` query just when there is a difference .. Please take a look at the examples in my update version.

Comment: @stack, that's why those `is null` check are present to fix the issue with plain `<>` not considering nulls. When column had a value and then it became null - you want to trigger, when column was null and then it received a value - you want to trigger, when the value of the column had changed - you want to trigger. That is exactly what code is doing.